# Make div work horizontally

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've 3 radio buttons on my website. These radio buttons are horizontally aligned. Now the problem is, I've designed responsive website and i want the radio buttons to be displayed vertically whenever the screen resolution is less than 768px. 
I've done so far is
HTML

```
<div style="float:left;width:60%;">
                <div class="radio"><input type="radio">Confirm</div>
                <div class="radio"><input type="radio">Not Confirm</div>
                <div class="radio"><input type="radio">Extend</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.radio{
   float:left; 
   width:33%;
}
```

This works well for horizontal align of radio buttons.

But this is what i tried for vertical, and it doesnt responded

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .radio{
    width:33%;
 }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need add `clear:both;`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .radio{
    width:33%;
    clear:both;
 }
}
```

if using float left all the elements that will occur would not have used clear: both;

this universal method

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! Exactly what i wanted.

Comment: And if i want change the width in @media as 50% then? Because when i define width:50% in media and 33% in css It takes 33% default and doesn't change to 50%

Comment: Well, usually 50% is half of the visible screen ... in the adaptive layout all% so if for example two blocks is 50% if the three blocks is 33.3%, etc. advise on this topic examine framevork bootstrap a lot of information on it and he light to master it immediately goes adaptability adaptive but can be turned off

Comment: incidentally noticed that you are present In-line styles <div style="float:left;width:60%;"> and they take precedence over this, it is desirable not to prescribe them because they will override the settings that you specified in the file styles